# Formula for if a cell is blank, It will consider the previous cell as the value for that cell and sum the cells together

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, currency, weekday

I am trying to figure out how to sum a row of cells where if a cell in the row has a letter, for example a letter "X", to consider the cell to the left of it in the row as a value for that cell when summing up the row. For my table the reason behind this is I have a table that is for a construction project work week where each day I list the amount of employees work that day. On their off day I still need to consider them for when I sum the project up and pay for their hotel on the days they don't work. Also the employee count per day can change throughout the duration of the project. Example of this bellow:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  
5  5  5  5  4  4  X  4
```

So for this A through G is considered Monday-Saturday. Monday-Thursday I have 5 employees, while on Friday-Sunday I will have 4 Employees even though the 4 employees didn't work on Sunday for their off day I still need to sum the week up to charge a daily hotel price since the 4 employees will come back the next monday, which is "H" above and continue to work.

So is there a formula where I if I am summing up the row and it finds an X then it will sum the previous cell two times? And I do not want to add employees to the Sunday column because I have another formula that sums the work days to charge their hourly pay rate.

Answer (score 1):

Enter this array formula in next cell ( with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd> )

```
=SUM(IF(COLUMN(A1:H1)<=COLUMNS(B1:H1),NOT(ISNUMBER(B1:H1)))*(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:H1),A1:H1,0)))+SUM(A1:H1)
```

[image]

**Obviously it won't consider if first cell contains an `X`.  Rest in any of the cell if `X` is there, it will add up the previous value twice**

**Moreover it'll work if cell contains any numeric character**

Answer (score 0):

If it's always about the Sunday containing an `X` or not then I guess this is what you mean:
`=IF(G2="X",SUM(A2:F2)+F2,SUM(A2:G2))`

Comment: What if the cells containing an X or instead of an x, just blank, come at random times through the work week?

Comment: So for each non-numeric value in the row see it as the closest value to the left. Can there be 2 days after eachother. What do you expect for the second blank then?

Comment: How about to just calculate blank values in between numerical values. so that when the last value is summed, it wont continue to sum blanks.